# LinkedIn Authentication error while comment post on Linkedin from Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, linkedin-api

Helllo,

I am working on `Rails application` where have to `authenticate with LinkedIn` and `comments post on linked`. I got below error:

```
LinkedIn::Errors::AccessDeniedError in AccountsController#share_message_linkedin

(403): Access to posting shares denied
```

I authenticate user and login successfully and fetch linkedin user image and other things but when `tried to comments post on behalf of user` then got error of access denied.

Where is i am wrong or any mistake. Any one have a experience or any trick here to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have w_share checked under the Application Permissions.

[image: Checked Correct Permissions]

You'll then be able to post shares to the users wall. I have code that demonstrates what can be done.

https://github.com/kaburkett/LinkedIn-Advanced-Share

demo:  http://www.datopstech.com/linkedin-share-tool/

Do keep in mind LinkedIn changed availability of several API endpoints on Feb 2015. If you are referencing old information, keep this in mind:

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

Comment: Thanks for answer, Actually in my app, I have full permission same which you describe here. But let me check with your code.

Comment: I tried your link to post message where successfully posted but not display on linkedin wall. When i can see posted content on my profile wall?

Comment: ohh Now i can see.. :) Now i have to implement it. Can i not do  only share message means small text on linked not need any other link and content link.

Comment: I am 90% sure you can omit parts of the share api that you dont want to use. I required them in my app with some javascript that prevents submission but you can edit that. Star and clone my repo on linkedin- and play around with what you need and dont need to include from there

Comment: I used but i still faced token issue. I got token like: 879axxxx-xxx2-4xxf-xxb5-xxxxcaec. Is this correct token? How long token? As per i check in api console there pass long token so i little bit confused in token.

Comment: my api key is this format: NNNLLLLLLLLLLL

where N = number and L= lowercase letter